# Filtering CollectionViewSource with multiple filters

Tags: wpf, collectionviewsource, icollectionview

I was reading this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26673.wpf-collectionview-tips.aspx and have tried to apply it to my code without success.

```
PendingTrucks = (CollectionView)new CollectionViewSource { Source = TruckLog }.View;
ParkedTrucks = (CollectionView)new CollectionViewSource { Source = TruckLog }.View;


PendingTrucks.Filter += PendingTrucks_Filter;
ParkedTrucks.Filter += PendingTrucks_Filter;

public static ICollectionView PendingTrucks
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public static ICollectionView ParkedTrucks
        {
            get; set;
        }



static bool PendingTrucks_Filter (object value)
{
            if (value is Truck truck)
            {
                return truck.ParkItem is null;
            }

            // Fallbackvalue 
            return true;
        }

        static bool ParkedTrucks_Filter (object value)
        {
            if (value is Truck truck)
            {
                return truck.status == 2;
            }

            // Fallbackvalue 
            return true;
        }
```

I am getting the following error: `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`.

The error shows when it tried to load the form with the Datagrid with the itemsource bound to the view.

This is the call stack I am getting:

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.CanAddNew.get()
    System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.System.ComponentModel.IEditableCollectionView.CanAddNew.get()
    System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnCoerceCanUserAddOrDeleteRows(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid, bool, bool)
    System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnCoerceCanUserAddRows(System.Windows.DependencyObject, object)
    System.Windows.DependencyObject.ProcessCoerceValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, ref System.Windows.EntryIndex, ref int, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, ref object, object, object, System.Windows.CoerceValueCallback, bool, bool, bool)
    System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, bool, bool, System.Windows.OperationType)
    System.Windows.DependencyObject.CoerceValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty)
    System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnItemsSourceChanged(System.Collections.IEnumerable, System.Collections.IEnumerable)
    System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.OnItemsSourceChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    ...
    [Call Stack Truncated]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

This is the source collection of the `ICollectionView`. You add/remove items from the collection, and the `ICollectionView` is updated automatically.

```
private ObservableCollection<Truck> Trucks { get; }
```

Your collection views which bind to the DataGrid:

```
public ICollectionView PendingTrucksCollectionView { get; }
public ICollectionView ParkedTrucksCollectionView { get; }
```

Initialize the source collection and views on the ViewModel constructor. Here you can pass an object that will populate the observable collection, or an IEnumerable to fill the truck collection.

```
public ViewModel() : this(Enumerable.Empty<Truck>())
{ }


public ViewModel(IEnumerable<Truck> trucks)
{
    // Collection Source
    Trucks = new ObservableCollection<Truck>(trucks);

    // Collection Views
    PendingTrucksCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Trucks);
    ParkedTrucksCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Trucks);

    // Collection View Filters
    PendingTrucksCollectionView.Filter = PendingTrucksFilter;
    ParkedTrucksCollectionView.Filter = ParkedTrucksFilter;
}

private bool PendingTrucksFilter(object value)
{
    return value is Truck truck && truck.ParkItem is null;
}

private bool ParkedTrucksFilter(object value)
{
    return value is Truck truck && truck.status == 2;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That appears like it would work. I just ditched the whole filter and used a method then on collectionchanged I trigger the filter method.